# Easy way to accept bitcoin payments without external service

Tags: client, payment, validation

Is there a way to accept Bitcoin payments without running a full node or rely on an external service?

I'm thinking in some way to validate the transaction and then broadcast it to the network.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're not running a Bitcoin client of some sort, or referencing a 3rd party (rely on an external service) then your usability will suffer.

For example you can create private keys and address pairs for receiving funds using a library, so you can accept payments just fine without a node or a 3rd party. The draw back is you don't have a way to monitor the blockchain, check for UTXOs, or push transactions.

If you're looking to do those things as well with as little 3rd party as possible, I'd suggest use a library to create addresses, and build transactions, and then line up a series of open API's that allow you to check the UTXO set, and push a signed transaction. If one fails, then hit the next one, and if that fails hit the next, etc. It's a little extra work, but you won't have to sign up with a service, you don't have to run a node, and you don't have to feel like you're relying on an API service since you'll have fall backs.

**Here are some push tx endpoints:**
https://api.blockcypher.com/v1/btc/main/txs/push
https://chain.so/api/v2/send_tx/BTC/
https://btc.blockr.io/api/v1/tx/push

**Here are some APIs to get the UTXO of an address**
https://blockchain.info/unspent?active=1bitcoineateraddressdontsendf59kue
https://chain.api.btc.com/v3/address/1bitcoineateraddressdontsendf59kue/unspent
https://api.smartbit.com.au/v1/blockchain/address/1bitcoineateraddressdontsendf59kue/unspent

Answer (score -1):

You can accept by having a QR code.  Where the sender will broadcast the transaction on your behalf.

Comment: but how do i check the payment has actually been done?

Comment: You could make this a better answer by explaining where the QR code comes from, and answering how to check that the transaction was broadcast.

Comment: I've downvoted this answer, because it doesn't provide sufficient explanation to address the answer fully.